# SAS : get the observation number of the max/min value of a variable

Tags: sas, database-partitioning, proc-sql

I am trying to get as a macro variable or a plain variable the number of the observation that is the min/max of one variable.

I can get easily the value of this min/max, via a proc sql

```
proc sql noprint;
select min(variable) into :minvariable
from have;
quit;
```

Or via a proc summary

```
proc summary data=want;
var variable;
output out=mintable min=minvariable;
run;
```

But I have not fouhd in either method an easy way to find the number of the observation this minimum corresponds to.

**Background :**
I want to separate my sorted database based on this observation number, because I know that sorted in the right way there is a global minimum, and my variable of interest follows a U-curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single pass through the data, using `retain`. Where the same min/max value occurs multiple times, the observation of the first one seen is stored.

```
data want ;
  set have end=eof ;
  retain minval minobs maxval maxobs ;

  if value < minval or missing(minval) then do ;
    minval = value ;
    minobs = _n_ ;
  end ;

  if value > maxval or missing(maxval) then do ;
    maxval = value ;
    maxobs = _n_ ;
  end ;

  if eof then output ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand you correct. You want to know at which Position your minvariable is at your ordered table? Then you can just run a datastep and write the Position (which is *_n_* in datastep) in a macrovariable (or data-variable if you prefer) when your minvariable is matching.

```
data _null_;

set have;

if variable =&minvariable then
call symputx("obsnr", _n_);
run;
```

This works if your minvariable is unique

Comment: I was hoping to do it in one step but it is precisely what I am loooking for. It does not seem to work though. I do not get any error when running your code, but when I try to call `%put &obsnr`, I get `WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OBSNR not resolved.` And indeed my minvariable is likely not unique.

Comment: The code worked for me with some testvalues. Are you sure variable =&minvariable matches in your case? Otherwise obsnr will never be created. I guess there is a solution to solve this in one step, but i have no spontaneous idea right now. If minvariable is not unique, you have to store every match in a different variable (nobs1,nobs2,...)

Comment: I have tried other ways and I am afraid I have some very close values, and maybe rounded problems...